# Does anybody know the origin of this song?

Tags: shabbat-songs

There is a song that in my synagogue they sing every shabat night before beginning kabalat shabat:

'אילו היה לי כוח הייתי יוצא לשוק הייתי מכריז ואומר שבת היום לה

(*If I had the strength I would go out to the market and I would declare and say that Shabbat is a day for Hashem*)

Does anybody know the origin of this song? I think i heard once that it was composed by an holocaust survivor that hated the shabbat when he was little because their parents forced him to keep it, but then during the holocaust that was the thing he missed the most, and he promised to himself that if he survived he would keep shabbat forever and go out in the streets saying how good it is, but i heard this a long time ago and i don't remember the details of the story... Does anybody know anything about it?

Comment: It's originally a Yiddish niggun that goes: "Ven ikh volt gehot koyakh volt ikh gelofn in di gasn un ikh volt geshrign hoykh shabes, heylige shabes!" See [here](http://www.bhol.co.il/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=3030056&forum_id=771).

Comment: @ezra it could have been hebrew before becoming yiddish

Comment: @DoubleAA - I feel like due to the nature and meaning of the song, it probably originated with R' Levi Yitzchak of Berditchev.

Comment: @Double AA - It definitely existed in Yiddish long before the Hebrew. It used to be sung already before WWII. As far as I know it is a Wiznitzer niggun. Already more than 40 years ago have I heard it in Bne berak at the Wiznitzer Tisch