What is this intro to this rendition of Kah Echsof?
My inability to hear lyrics, and my inabilities in Yiddish require me to ask the fine folk here what exactly is being said in the first words that precede Kah Echsof in this rendition.
Could someone transliterate and translate for me, and for a nice bonus, give me some kind of context of why they said it - is this unique to this rendition or does it have a history?
Thanks.

Always wondered that too!

My favourite song :) Yosef Moshe Kahane is my go to for Shabbos medleys :)

@Shmuel mine too, and yes, they really have a way of bringing out the tangibility of the Kedushat Shabbat

The words are (transliterated using the singers' Yiddish dialect):

װען איך װאָלט געהאַט כּוח
װאָלט איך געלאָפֿן אין די גאַסן
און איך װאָלט געשריגן הױך
שבת, הײליקע שבת
Ven ikh volt gehat koyekh
Volt ikh gelofn in de gasn
In ikh volt geshrign hoyekh
Shabes, haylike Shabes
If I had the strength,
I would run in the streets
And I would shout loudly:
Shabbos, holy Shabbos

I know of a B section, which is:

שבת, שבת, הײליקע שבת
שבת, שבת, הײליקע שבת
שבת היום לה׳
שבת היום לה׳
Shabes, Shabes, haylike Shabes
Shabes, Shabes, haylike Shabes
Shabes, hayo(y)m lashem
Shabes, hayo(y)m lashem
Shabbos, Shabbos, holy Shabbos
Shabbos, Shabbos, holy Shabbos
Shabbos, the day is for Hashem
Shabbos, the day is for Hashem

You can hear a version of this song with the B section here.
I don't have a history of the text, but from what I can tell online, it's an old song and we don't know the author.

Thank you so much, I am in awe. Is it completely separate from Kah Echsof or is there an association?

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83486/759

@RabbiKaii I don't know of any association between the two, and the only place I hear them together is this recording.
